# Which version of Stellarium made you fly from one moon to another?

Tags: observational-astronomy, stellarium

I recall a version of Stellarium (it was the very first time I had Stellarium) many years ago that made you fly between moons of the same system if you changed celestial bodies. E.g. if you were on Titan and wanted to go to Mimas or to the parent planet Saturn, it made it appear as if you actually flew from Titan to Mimas or to Saturn, unlike in later versions in which you just immediately teleport to the other body. Do you know which version that was?

I think it was 0.12.x but I checked one out, you still teleport immediately to the other body. It may have been an even older version. What else I can tell you about that version is that on the frequency of meteors you could only pick either 0 or 10 or 100 or 1000 per hour or so, you couldn't enter a random number unlike in newer versions. It's a pity Stellarium disabled the translunar flights (or can you enable it somewhere?). Maybe someone around here knows which version that would be.

Comment: Are you sure it was Stellarium and not Celestia (which does do what you describe)?

Comment: @ProfRob Of course it was Stellarium. Celestia is no observatory program in the first place, and its latest version is from 2011 afaik. I also described picking the number of meteors per hour which should put things clear anyway. The older version I checked out had it similar but the celestial body change didn't make you fly to the other body either. On the Stellarium I remember, the flight to the other body was very fast (like light speed), so that you were almost immediately on the other body. But no teleportation, it looked as if you flew there.

Comment: Stellarium allows scripting and ships with quite a few. Maybe such script exist?

Comment: To ProfRob's upvoter: It. Was. Stellarium. There's no debate about this.

Comment: @John. There is no reason to be so combative and defensive. No one owes you an answer and ProfRob was trying to be helpful.

Comment: @f_n_lyre The upvoters obviously still claim it was Celestia. Both upvotes came after my clarification that it was Stellarium. But you can conclude it from the mention of the meteor shower frequency already.